# Solving Normal Probability Distribution (PDF) and Cumulative Probability Distribution (CDF) for given X and comparing to Excel's NORM.DIST() function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have been trying to understand and implement the Excel function `NORM.DIST(x, mean, standard_deviation, cumulative)` in another programming language. There exist libraries in `R (“stats”)` and `Python ("scipy.stats")` that are not handy for me.

There is a documentation for that Excel function [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/normdist-function-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58).

Based on that documentation and other sources I have seen that the equation for the normal probability/density function is:

$$f(x, \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}\sigma}e^{-(\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})}$$

I am solving for given $x=1, \mu=0, \sigma=1$

In Excel is `NORM.DIST(1,0,1,FALSE)` which gives a result of $0.241970725$

By using an online calculator **Symbolab** I am solving this equation and it gives me the same result check [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Ccdot%5Cpi%7D%5Ccdot1%7De%5E%7B-%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1-0%5Cright)%5E2%7D%7B2%5Ccdot1%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)%7D%20).

Now when I try to solve for Cumulative Probability/Density Distribution, based on the Excel documentation I have to solve for the integral from negative infinity to x of the given formula, that takes form of the equation:

$$f(x, \mu, \sigma) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}\sigma}e^{-(\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}})}dt$$

Using **Symbolab** when I try to solve this function diverges (check [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Ccdot%5Cpi%7D%5Ccdot1%7De%5E%7B-%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1-0%5Cright)%5E2%7D%7B2%5Ccdot1%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)%7D%20)), but in Excel `NORM.DIST(1,0,1,TRUE)` it gives a result of $0.841344746$

Can someone try to solve this integral, if I am doing something wrong and if there is any step that I am missing trying to solve the cumulative density function (CDF).

Answer (score 1):

They are different!

In fact, $f(x_0)$ (PDF) returns the weight of point $x_0$ in comparison to other points and has no direct meaning unless you integrate it on some interval containing it:
$$P(x_0-\epsilon \leqslant x \leqslant x_0+\epsilon) = \int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon} f(x) dx \approx 2\epsilon f(x_0)$$
That means probability that $X$ occurs near $x_0$ is like a linear function on length of interval by derivative equals to $f(x_0)$.

But $F(x_0)$ (CDF) has self meaning of probability:
$$P(x \leqslant x_0) = F(x_0)$$
That means probability of $X$ occurs before $x_0$.

Now for your comment and reason of diversity. When you integrate $f$ to get $F$, you should change variable of $f(x)$ to $f(t)$ and at end it replaced by $x$ in upper boundary to reach $F(x)$:
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt \overset{\text{For Normal Dist.}}{=======} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}.\sigma}exp(-\frac{({\color{red}t}-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}) dt$$
That you wrongly write $x$ instead of ${\color{red}t}$ And then replaced it by $1$ before getting integration. In fact, you integrate of a constant in infinite domain that diverges obviously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that there are different, I am just trying to solve based on that given equation for CDF. I just don't know what is behind that EXCEL function actually and how to solve it step by step.

Comment: I add some explanation that address your problem.